# How to respond List<> from a RESTful Service using @GET

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web

This is how far i have come trying to respond with a `List<>` of `Users` to a Client . Every time i get `Error 500` so i tried to respond with just a `String` and it worked so there is not a problem with the server/client communication. I searched the Internet and i found some examples that they returned `Lists<>` without error but i can't get mine to work.

User Class

```
package org.cs131111.user;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private String studentID;
    private String Fname;
    private String Lname;
    private int semester;

    public User(){}

    public User(String sID,String fname,String lname,int sem){
        this.studentID=sID;
        this.Fname=fname;
        this.Lname=lname;
        this.semester = sem;
    }


   public String getId() {
      return studentID;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public void setId(String id) {
      this.studentID = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return Fname+"_"+Lname;
   }


   @XmlElement
   public void setFName(String name) {
      this.Fname = name;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public void setLName(String name) {
      this.Lname = name;
   }
   public int getSemester() {
      return semester;
   }
   @XmlElement
   public void setSemester(int semester) {
      this.semester = semester;
   }        

}
```

UserList class

```
package org.cs131111.user;

import org.cs131111.db.DatabaseConnection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UserList {
    public List<User> list = null;

    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        User stud = null; 
        DatabaseConnection newc = null;
        newc = new DatabaseConnection();
        list = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            newc.results=newc.query.executeQuery("select * from `students`");
        while(newc.results.next()){
            stud = new User(newc.results.getString("studentid"),newc.results.getString("fname"),newc.results.getString("lname"),newc.results.getInt("semester"));
            list.add(stud);
            System.out.println(stud.getId()+" "+stud.getName());
        }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        newc.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

UserService class

```
package org.cs131111.user;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {

   UserList userOb = new UserList();

   @GET
   @Path("/users")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<User> getUsers(){
       final List<User> users = userOb.getAllUsers();
      return users;
   }    
}
```

The Client

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="User.User"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="java.net.MalformedURLException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page import="java.net.HttpURLConnection"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<%
          try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:11118/EclassServer/webresources/UserService/users");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        List<User> u= (List<User>)conn.getContent();
        out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String test=u.get(1).getId();
        out.println(test);
        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
 %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server's stack trace

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
    at org.apache.jsp.clientGet_jsp._jspService(clientGet_jsp.java:80)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What's the error? Show the full stack trace.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Edited the original post

Comment: What happens if you perform the request from a REST client, like Postman, instead from from a JSP page?

Comment: Same thing . Error 500 .Although  I am not very familiar with Postman with where to see more details about the errors.

Comment: The stack trace you posted doesn't help. What we are looking for is the exception thrown by your REST service and not the one you threw in your JSP.

Comment: No exception from the Service. Everything till the line before the return works perfectly. So i can't see why it will have an expception returning the List<> object .

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're using a REST service because it seems that your DB and your servlet are on the same machine so you can access the DB directly from your servlet (no need  for a REST requst)?

Comment: @dsp_user I will transfer the db on a running server i have when i can. For now i am testing locally.

Comment: Regardless, you can still access your DB using plain JDBC (or some O/RM library) and have your User list accessible to JSP via HttpServletRequest.setAttribute("userList", users); Then in your JSP you access the list by calling List<User> list = (List<User>) request
     .getAttribute("userList"); I'm basically saying that I don't see a good reason for a REST service at all.

Comment: the assignment wants REST services, so i have to deliver REST services

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this as a comment so here it is. You can't really expect HttpUrlConnection.getContent to return  a List of User instances. From the Javadoc

> This method first determines the content type of the object by calling
>   the getContentType method. If this is the first time that the
>   application has seen that specific content type, a content handler for
>   that content type is created:
>
> > If the application has set up a content handler factory instance using
> >     the setContentHandlerFactory method, the createContentHandler method
> >     of that instance is called with the content type as an argument; the
> >     result is a content handler for that content type. If no content
> >     handler factory has yet been set up, or if the factory's
> >     createContentHandler method returns null, then the application loads
> >     the class named:

The usual way to get the content (when using HttpUrlConnection) is by using BufferedReader in combination with InputStreamReader something like

```
if(resCode==200){
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));          
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

}
```

But even now you will only get your User list as one large string (formatted as XML) and you should use an object mapper to convert the content/entity string to a List of User instances.

If, on the other hand, you used a Jersey client, it would be able to do the conversion automatically for you (it uses JAXB under the hood). Your Jersey client code might look something like (not tested)

```
WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:11118/EclassServer/webresources/UserService/users").build()); 

GenericType<List<User>> genType = new GenericType<List<User>>();

List<User> userList =(String) target.request().accept(MediaType.XML_APPLICATION).get(genType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a correct root element. You've added the [@XmlRootElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) annotation to the User class, but it's not the root element as you're returning a list of users not a single user.

I recommend to specify a XSD and generate the JAXB classes rather than writing them yourself.

Comment: I did what u said with the @XmlRootElement and the error now is this `Severe:   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<org.cs131111.user.User>. `

Comment: @Segmentation Please update your question with the XSD.

Comment: I think the User class requires a @XmlType annotation. But I'm not sure this is enough. You need a root element class which has a list of Users. I'm not sure if JAX-RS will auto-generate this for you.